# Javascript XMLHTTP request only works once?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, xmlhttprequest

This is a part of my code:

```
function addText(id, type){
    alert("ID="+id);
    alert("TYPE="+type);

    var title = getData("title", id);
    var text = getData("text", id);
    var imageUrl = getData("imageUrl", id);

    document.getElementById("contentArea").innerHTML += '<div id="' + id + '"> </div>';

    if(type == 1){
        allText = html1.responseText;
        titleReplace = "K" + id + "title";
        textReplace = "K" + id + "text";
        imageReplace = "K" + id + "image";
        allText.replace("K1title", titleReplace);
        allText.replace("K1text", textReplace);
        allText.replace("K1image", imageReplace);
    }

    document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = allText;

    document.getElementById(titleReplace).innerHTML = title;
    document.getElementById(textReplace).innerHTML = text;
    document.getElementById(imageReplace).src = imageUrl;

}

function getData(Parameter, id){
    var result = undefined;
    var URL = phpGetURL + "?par=" + Parameter + "&id=" + id;

    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open('GET', URL ,false);
    xmlhttp.send();
    result = xmlhttp.responseText;
    xmlhttp.abort();

    //lert(result);
    return result;
}
```

And this is a part from the index.php where is call the function 4 times:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/dataManager.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> addText(1, 1); addText(2, 1); addText(3, 1); addText(4, 1); </script>
```

The first one displays, the second one displays but not with the replaced text. The fourth and the fifth doesn't display at all.

It's gets the data from a php script that gets it from a MYSQL database.

I don't get it to work.

thx

Comment: Can you use jQuery?

Comment: `open('GET', URL ,false);` sync ajax is deprecated & bad, use callbacks, promise, fetch, $.ajax or events

Comment: @Praveen Kumar Yes I can

Comment: @Endless That works fine because somewhere else in the script, i used it to get html from a txt file and that works

Comment: Yea, but even if it works, you **shouldn't use it**! One day it won't work... That's why its *deprecated*

Comment: @Endless I agree but I don't have that much time for this project, it needs to run. When it's online I can improve it with a better solution

Comment: @JulesHummelink Use `$.get()` from jQuery and use a call back function to set the `.html()` of the element.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue while working on an extension for chrome.
You should may try to initialize the "XMLHttpRequest()"-instance at the very beginning of your code, so that is only created once.

I'm posting this for others, because i've read that you had to solve this problem fast, years ago... So it is not urgent anymore i guess...

Comment: No, trying to run multiple requests through a single instance of XMLHttpRequest is likely to **cause** problems. It won't solve them.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).